BIOS-locked samsung laptop
I recently purchased a second-hand Samsung Book 4 Pro, but unfortunately, it is BIOS-locked. When I turn it on, I’m prompted to scan a QR code, which generates a 24-digit code. I tried using the website https://www.biosbug.com/, but they don't seem to support a 24-digit code.

You have to obtain the password from the previous owner, otherwise use it "as is".

@ChanganAuto Couldn't OP remove the CMOS battery, wait a few minutes, and put it back in? (Assuming that BitLocker or some third party isn't installed onto the machine.)

No, if it's the firmware's (UEFI). And no, there are no hacks, codes, online calculators, etc. for a password protected UEFI. OP with proof of purchase can maybe get help from Samsung but all they'll do eventually is to replace the motherboard out of warranty, i.e., the cost will be the same or higher than a new laptop.

@Colin - Removing the battery out of a laptop has not reset the firmware settings in over a decade.

@ChanganAuto Oh yes, you're correct. I didn't think about UEFI.

Contact those who sold you the laptop and let them know that the device is BIOS locked and you need help to unlock it.

If it were trivial to unlock BIOS/UEFI systems, either through some unlock service like you appear to be trying to use, or via a hardware "hack" like removing the CMOS battery or manipulating a jumper, the security of these systems would be laughable, as every person with any interest in compromising them would be fully aware of each of these unlock or circumvention methods.
For this reason it is good that these methods do not work any longer.
This leaves you with two options:

Contact the seller and ask them to clear the restrictions.
Use the computer as is.


Is there a newer security measure imposed against BIOS reset effected by removing the CMOS battery?

Hackers are still smart, Highly effective, but if the attacker knows how to short specific pins on the motherboard, the password might be bypassed. The BIOS password.

What about hackers who know how to short specific pins on the motherboard? Is it happening?

I asked AI and it suggested that some high skill hackers can recognize those pins and short them to bypass the BIOS password, but maybe the AI is hallucinating lol.

"I asked AI...", I'm sorry, but I find this very frustrating. I assumed your questions were real and based on good intent.
